# How to add Agora.IO into my .NET MAUI project

Tags: android, maui, agora.io

I want to add the AgoraIO calling feature to my .net MAUI app, but I couldn't find the doc for .NET MAUI. They only provide doc for xamarin which doesn't supports in .NET MAUI.
Does Agora supports .NET MAUI?